# Show sum Column SQL code

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I need show sum col(item) under col with SQL code ? it's possible

```
 Code            item                         
 ----            ----               
 1               30          
 3               40        
 4               50
 9               80
----             ----
Total            200
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `Rollup` to get the summary row

```
SELECT CASE
         WHEN Grouping(code) = 1 THEN 'Total'
         ELSE Cast(code AS VARCHAR(50))
       END,
       Sum(item)
FROM   Yourtable
GROUP  BY code WITH rollup
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select * from (select * from #Table1
union
select null, sum(item) item from #Table1)a
order by item
```

Comment: though this may work ,this accesses table twice.see above solutions

Answer (score 1):

```
DECLARE @Table1  TABLE 
    (Code int, item int)
;

INSERT INTO @Table1
    (Code, item)
VALUES
    (1, 30),
    (3, 40),
    (4, 50),
    (9, 80)
;
```

Script :

```
select Code , sum(item)item
 from @Table1
 group by GROUPING SETS((Code) , ())
 order by Code DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Select
   Code,
   item 
from
   @ table_name 
Union All
select
   Null,
   sum(item)item 
from
   @ table_name
```

As we are using union all so distinct and order by operation will be saved.